# Вывести лог за определенное время

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, администрирование, скрипт, выборка

Есть "программулина" которая ведет свой лог. Формат лога следующий  "15.02.2018 14:59:17 -  какое-то событие" Строки по датам могут достигать огромных размеров. Вопрос: как с помощью grep или find вывести период времени, например вывести лог за промежуток времени от "15.02.2018 14:59:17 до 15.03.2018 14:59:17" Спасибо.

Comment: А у вас это как сервис запущенно или другими способами? Если сервисом и этот systemd то там уже все можно фильтровать и обрезать в любом временном промежутке, читайте`man journalctl`

Answer (score 3):

Выбрать интервал времени регулярным выражением из лог-файла - задача трудоемкая.

Я бы предложил использовать `awk`.

В соответствии с [примером](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706095/filter-log-file-entries-based-on-date-range) можно попробовать сделать так:

```
 awk -vDate='2018-02-15 14:59:17' -vDate2='2018-03-15 14:59:17' '{split($1, d, ".");logDate=d[3]"-"d[2]"-"d[1]" "$2;if (logDate > Date && logDate < Date2) print $0}' message.log
```

Основная задача тут - преобразовать дату в "правильный" формат "yyyy-mm-dd". Поскольку в лог-файлe дата представлена в формате "dd.mm.yyyy", то даты сравнить как строки (или преобразовать в timestamp) не получится. Точнее, сравнить получится, но будет неверный результат.

Поэтому для программы `awk` задаем границы времени (переменные Date и Date2) в формате "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS", и к этому же формату приводим дату из лог файла (функция split), и далее проверяем эту дату с попаданием в диапазон.

Не знаю, насколько хорошо в этом случае сравнивать даты как строки, но при желании можно предварительно конвертировать значения в timestamp.

Comment: чудес, увы, не бывает. например, `10.03.2018` — оказывается, больше, чем `09.04.2018`: `$ echo "10.03.2018" | awk '$1" "$2 > "09.04.2018"'`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, как-то я опрометчиво не обратил внимание на формат даты. Но вариант рабочий с небольшими дополнениями.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам непринципиально (а в рамках реальной практики обычно так и бывает), то просмотрите логи отдельно:

```
cat log.txt |grep "^15.02.2018 14:59:" >>parsedlog.txt
cat log.txt |egrep "^15.02.2018 1[5-9]"\|"15.02 2" >>parsedlog.txt
cat log.txt |egrep "^1[6-9].02.2018"\|"^2[0-9].02.2018" >>parsedlog.txt
...
```

Возможно, будет сподручнее запилить *однострочный скрипт на перле*™, который будет принимать параметры времени начала и конца просмотра и, проходя по файлу, выводить только события, случившиеся в указанном промежутке.

Comment: *Useless use of cat*, можете погуглить.

Comment: Что же вы `cut` везде суете господа... ВСЕ программы из util-linux gnu-coreutils grep sed awk .. принимают  stdin

Comment: Привычка. Не люблю грепать по файлам (кроме как в случае с -R), люблю по stdin'у. @Hellseher ну так он и принимает stdin, правда?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Ночные комментарии. Имел в виду, что можно опустить `cat`  - есть функционал чтения из файла `grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]`

Comment: @Hellseher угу. Старая привычка, ничего не могу поделать — руки набирают `cat` автономно.

Comment: @Hellseher, посмотрите мой первый комментарий к этому ответу, обычно находятся ссылки не только про *cat*. Spoiler: в некоторых случаях  и *grep*, и *wc*, и другие могут быть так же излишними.

Answer (score 0):

Нубовский вариант, но рабочий:

```
cat log.txt | grep -n '15.02.2018 12:00:00'
```

смотрю номер строки, запоминаю.

```
cat log.txt | grep -n '15.03.2018 12:00:00'
```

опять смотрю, запоминаю.

И финальная команда для вывода:

```
sed -n 666,1488p /path/to/log/file
```

---

[666,1488p - номера строк. У вас будут другие цифры]

---

Answer (score 0):

ключевая проблема — это трудность сортировки строк, в которых компоненты даты вписаны в «неестественном» порядке, т.е. когда компоненты перечислены **не** в порядке убывания «старшинства» (сначала год, затем месяц, затем число).

теоретиески тут два пути решения:

1. извлекать символы, содержащие дату (и опционально — время) и преобразовывать их в тип, поддающийся сортировке (какой-нибудь там datetime, unixtimestamp и т.п.), а затем уже сортировать по этой дате. **см. примечание ниже**.
2. переставить символы так, чтобы компоненты даты были перечислены в «естественном» порядке: «15.03.2018» превратить в «2018.03.15», а затем сортировать как самые обычные строки.

второй путь, теоретически, менее накладный, чем первый.

---

для удобства удаления строк, которые будут «выше» указанной стартовой даты, можно добавить перед сортировкой строку с этой датой, а потому удалить все строки с первой по эту фиктивную. аналогично и с конечной датой.

стартовая дата будет включена в результат, а конечная дата — нет (будут включены строки, находящиеся выше).

вот пример скрипта на языке, понятном интепретатору *sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh

from="2018.02.15 14:59:17"
to="2018.03.15 14:59:17"
logfile="/путь/к/файлу/с/логом"

{ cat "${logfile} | sed -r 's/^(..)\.(..)\.(....)/\3.\2.\1/'; \
echo "${from}"; echo "${to}"; } | sort | \
sed "1,/^${from}\$/d;/^${to}\$/,\$d"
```

если в файле с логом содержатся такие строки:

```
15.02.2018 14:59:16 лог1
15.02.2018 14:59:17 лог2
15.03.2018 14:59:16 лог3
15.03.2018 14:59:17 лог4
```

то запуск скрипта выведет из них две средние:

```
2018.02.15 14:59:17 лог2
2018.03.15 14:59:16 лог3
```

---

начальную и конечную даты, указанные в скрипте в переменных `from`
 и `to` соответственно, можно «округлять» до любого символа.

например, с точностью до минуты:

```
2018.02.15 14:59
```

или до месяца:

```
2018.02
```

---

#### примечание по поводу синтаксического разбора даты

если дата, как в примере из вопроса, записана в «неестественном» порядке, то «искусственный интеллект», заложенный в алгоритмы разбора, запросто даёт сбой.

например, дата `16.02.2018`, при использовании в качестве парсера программы *awk*, предложенной в ответе @de_frag, оказывается «больше», чем `15.03.2018`:

```
$ echo "16.02.2018 00:00:00" | awk '$1" "$2 > "15.03.2018 00:00:00"'
16.02.2018 00:00:00
```

---

ну и, конечно, никакой «искуственный интеллект не поможет определить, какая дата записана в виде `01.02.2018` — первое февраля или второе января.

Comment: *Useless use of cat*, можете погуглить.

Comment: Первый путь как раз легче, почитайте на досуге *man date*.