# Отсортировать и очистить массив

Tags: linux, bash

Категорически приветствую!

Существует некий массив

```
# printf '%s\n' "${FILES[@]}"
s3:/some/path/file-10-Jan-2018-18-42-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-31-Oct-2018-22-11-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-11-Feb-2018-11-42-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-20-Mar-2018-13-42-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-01-Apr-2018-14-41-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-28-Aug-2018-25-11-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-May-2018-23-41-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-28-Aug-2018-25-12-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Jun-2018-03-22-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-28-Aug-2018-25-21-24.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-23-Sep-2018-13-11-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-24-Nov-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-23-00-01.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-22-00-01.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-21-00-01.sql.gz
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как его отсортировать по дате от самого нового к самому старому и затем удалить всё, кроме 5 самых новых строк?

Comment: А как Вы уже пробовали?

Comment: для сортировки дату надо привести к нормальному виду: год, затем месяц, затем день. см., например, ответы к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/872653/178576)

Comment: У вас в 3х местах время 25-12-54 думаю это случайно, привел к 23-12-54

Comment: @0xdb да, собсно, так `read -d'\n' -a FILES < <(printf '%s\n' "${FILES[@]}"|tac|head -n5)` но по очевидным причинам которые я не увидел в мае, это не очень правильно и всё это время я видел без бэкапов :)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это слишком просто :)

Comment: @Hellseher ага, очень затроил под вечер, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В одну строку:

```
readarray -t FILES < <(printf '%s\n' "${FILES[@]}" | \
    sort -k4nr -k3Mr -k2nr -k5nr -k6nr -k7nr -t- | head -n5)
```

Или можно без пайпа и printf:

```
readarray -t FILES \
    < <(head -n5 < <(sort -k4nr -k3Mr -k2nr -k5nr -k6nr -k7nr -t- <<<"${FILES[@]}"))
```

Comment: Не будет работать точно. Каждый сорт по позиции сбивает предедущую. Нжна конвертация в унифорную дату что то типа Unix time.

Comment: Не будет или не работает? У меня к примеру норм сортирует. При всем уважении к Вашей репутации Вы бы проверили сначала.

Comment: Это был мой первый вариант. Представите, что года разные? Или время очень разбито по часам или все дни календаря...

Comment: Я об этом тоже подумал когда уже Вам ответил. Набросал еще строк и sort -k3Mr -k5nr -k6nr -k7nr -t- вроде как все решило

Comment: Однако :), не добил. Результат тот же с меньшим усилием. Я все же предложил автору использовать цифровой штамп времени за вместо "удобочитаемой" даты..

Comment: Получается `sort`  сохраняет предыдущее состояние? а не сбивает по новому столбцу? Добавьте вывод для наглядности, так легче читать с промером "выхлопа".

Answer (score 2):

Если закрыть глаза на то что автор задал время в 25 часовом дапозоне:

> 28-Aug-2018-25-12-54.sql

логика следующая:

- разбить путь на левая часть до даты, часть с датой, удалить расширение
- конвертировать дату в Unix time
- собрать путь
- отсортировать и конвертировать путь обратно как было

Получившийся код

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File : 879812.sh

FILES=("s3:/some/path/file-10-Jan-2018-18-42-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-31-Oct-2018-22-11-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-11-Feb-2018-11-42-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-20-Mar-2018-13-42-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-01-Apr-2018-14-41-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-28-Aug-2018-23-11-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-22-May-2018-23-41-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-28-Aug-2018-23-12-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-22-Jun-2018-03-22-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-28-Aug-2018-23-21-24.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-23-Sep-2018-13-11-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-24-Nov-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-23-00-01.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-22-00-01.sql.gz"
       "s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-21-00-01.sql.gz")

for f in ${FILES[@]}; do
    path="$(echo "$f" | awk -F"-" '{print $1}')"
    date="$(echo "${f/.sql.gz/}"  | awk -F"-" '{print $2,$3,$4,$5":"$6":"$7}')"
    echo "${path}-$(date -d"$date" +%s).sql.gz"
done | sort -rn | head -n5 | while read -r f; do
    path="$(echo "$f" | awk -F"-" '{print $1}')"
    date="$(echo "${f/.sql.gz/}" | awk -F"-" '{print $2}')"
    echo "${path}-$(date -d@$date +%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S).sql.gz"
done
# End of 879812.sh
```

Получим:

```
~$ ./879812.sh
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-23-00-01.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-22-00-01.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-21-00-01.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz
s3:/some/path/file-22-Dec-2018-12-11-54.sql.gz
```

Заменил неточное время (может опечатка автора)

```
date: invalid date ‘28 Aug 2018 25:21:24’
```

Работает только с данным примером путей

**Ссылки**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242986/sort-logs-by-date-field-in-bash
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-epoch-in-bash
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371248/how-to-convert-timestamps-to-dates-in-bash